# How to center sized div columns within a div row in Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

- My row takes a good chunk of real estate with no css styling supplied by me. I like that part fine.
- My column divs have a width, so on a large display they won't stretch. I like that, too.
- I would like to have those div columns centered within the div row. Before I move to apply my own styling to do this, I wanted to know if there's a Bootstrap way to achieve it. I found `text-center` and `center-box` online but neither seems to be working in my case.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

Example:

```
<div class="container" style="border: 2px #000 solid;">
    <div class="row text-center center-box" style="text-align: center;  border: 3px red solid"> 
        <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color: yellow; border: 1px green solid; width: 50px; height: 100px;">text</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color: yellow; border: 1px green solid; width: 50px; height: 100px;">text</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color: yellow; border: 1px green solid; width: 50px; height: 100px;">text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The red border shows the div row very well stretched. The div columns are limited to roughly 150px of width together. They stay aligned to the left. Can we center them using Bootstrap tricks?

**Suggested by sachMati but not working for me**

```
<div class="container" style="border: 2px #000 solid;">
    <div class="row justify-content-center" style="text-align: center; border: 3px red solid;">
        <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color: yellow; border: 1px green solid; width: 50px; height: 100px;">text</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color: yellow; border: 1px green solid; width: 50px; height: 100px;">text</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color: yellow; border: 1px green solid; width: 50px; height: 100px;">text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you prefer Bootstrap version 3 over 4?

Comment: Why are you defining a `width` for the `col-sm-4` class? the point of the column is setting the width of the content. If you want them to stay small on bigger screens you can also use the other classes like `col-md-*` `col-lg-*`

Comment: Right now, using ver 3. The need for width is there based on some context. I don't want to take you through a long story. That's why I showed a simple example.

Comment: @IvanS95 Will do some reading on the col options. Frankly, I was following an example online without thinking of going to Bootstrap university first. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know why use `width` to define a width for the `col-*` classes, as that's the point of the `col-*` classes in the first place. But if you're using **Bootstrap 4** you can just add the `justify-content-center` to the `row` div and it will center its content (if it has space available).

You could specify a smaller column for larger devices, like if you use `col-sm-4` for small screens, you could use `col-lg-2` for larger screens, avoiding setting a specific width, if that gets the look you need of course, since setting an explicit `width` defeats the purpose of the column classes.

**Try this in full screen**

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container" style="border: 2px #000 solid;">
  <div class="row justify-content-center" style="text-align: center;  border: 3px red solid">
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color: yellow; border: 1px green solid; width: 50px; height: 100px;">text</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color: yellow; border: 1px green solid; width: 50px; height: 100px;">text</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color: yellow; border: 1px green solid; width: 50px; height: 100px;">text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For **Bootstrap 3** you could try adding the flex behaviors and it should work pretty much the same; or you can stick to Bootstrap using the `offset-*` classes.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container" style="border: 2px #000 solid;">
  <div class="row flex" style="text-align: center;  border: 3px red solid">
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color: yellow; border: 1px green solid; width: 150px; height: 100px;">text</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color: yellow; border: 1px green solid; width: 150px; height: 100px;">text</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color: yellow; border: 1px green solid; width: 150px; height: 100px;">text</div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Offset  -->

<div class="container" style="border: 2px #000 solid; margin-top: 20px">
  <div class="row" style="text-align: center;  border: 3px red solid">
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-3" style="background-color: yellow; border: 1px green solid; height: 100px;">text</div>
    <div class="col-xs-2" style="background-color: yellow; border: 1px green solid; height: 100px;">text</div>
    <div class="col-xs-2" style="background-color: yellow; border: 1px green solid; height: 100px;">text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess I'll need to update to Bootstrap 4. You have `jusstify-content-center` with double `s` and `text-align: center;`. So which directive does the actual centering? The class or the style?

Comment: @jacekn my bad lol, it was the style, and it was also centering the text inside, but since Bootstrap 4 uses Flexbox I would stick to the `justify-content-center` class.. I updated my answer to provide a workaround for Bootstrap 3 as well

Comment: `display: flex;` and `justify-content: center;` worked for me earlier. But when I added another row to the page, things got out of whack. Let me upgrade to ver 4 and see what happens. I might need some `clearfix` patch.

Comment: @jacekn added an example with `offset` as well, removed the widths and reduced the size of the columns, all this can be modified to your liking. That might also be because I referenced the `.row` class lol, you should add a new class like `.flex` for example and add the properties only to that class

Answer (score 1):

If you want center content in a row of container try this

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row justify-content-center">
       <!-- content of row  -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've tried this earlier. It doesn't work for me. Do you actually see this working?